# JDB: DB2-Query with WITH clause and two host variables does not work

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I've optimized my DB2-query with a WITH-clause. Now it is fast, but does not work under JDBC anymore. Does anyone has an idea? Thanks!

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT ID_EINSENDUNG, BEURTEILUNG, VERSANDDAT_BVD, LASTUSER 
FROM BVDT.TEINSENDUNG_BVD WHERE VERSANDDAT_BVD = 
'2008-02-26' --HOST VARIABLE 1
) 
SELECT ID_EINSENDUNG, VERSANDDAT_BVD FROM tmp WHERE ID_EINSENDUNG > 
4100  --HOST VARIABLE 2
```

> Error Message: ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 SQLState: 42815
>   ErrorCode: -4461

Java Code:

```
public DBCursor searchViewLandwirtOhrmarke() throws Exception {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("WITH tmp AS " +
            "(SELECT ID_EINSENDUNG, BEURTEILUNG, VERSANDDAT_BVD, LASTUSER FROM BVDT.TEINSENDUNG_BVD WHERE VERSANDDAT_BVD = ?) " +
            "SELECT ID_EINSENDUNG, VERSANDDAT_BVD FROM tmp WHERE ID_EINSENDUNG > ?");


    prepareStatement(stringBuilder.toString());

    ps.setDate(1, DateUtils.getSQLDate("26.02.2008"));  
    ps.setInt(2,new Integer(4100));

    executeCursorSelect();
    return this;
}   

public EinsendungBvd nextViewLandwirtOhrmarke() throws Exception {
    if (endFetch()) {
        return null;
    }
    EinsendungBvd result = new EinsendungBvd(dbConn);
    result.setId_einsendung(new Integer(rs.getInt(1)));
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        result.setId_einsendung(null);
    }
    result.setVersanddat_bvd(rs.getDate(11));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a date format problem to me. Try changing your date in `ps.setDate(1, DateUtils.getSQLDate("26.02.2008"));` to `ps.setDate(1, DateUtils.getSQLDate("2008-02-26"));`. I don't know the DateUtil specs, so this is just a wild guess.. (see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_sqlstatevalues.htm) for a list of SQLSTATE/ERRORCODES)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that. DateUtils create a java.sql.Date out of a European date format string like 'DD.MM.YYYY'. I don't think that is the problem.
But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at IBM DB2 LUW version 9.7 [**Error codes issued by the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjcsqc.html) for error code `-4461`:

> -4461 text-from-getMessage 42815
>
> Explanation: The specified value is invalid or out of range.
>
> User response: Call SQLException.getMessage to retrieve specific information about the problem.

Things to try:

1. Log the value of `SQLException.getMessage()`.
2. Verify the data types for `VERSANDDAT_BVD` and `ID_EINSENDUNG`.
3. Test the query with one parameter at a time; isolate which parameter is the violator.
4. Verify `DateUtils.getSQLDate()` is parsing your date string correctly; compare the result of `Date.getTime()` on the `Date` from `DateUtils.getSQLDate()`and the `Date` from [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)`.parse()`.